# How do I add domain to the jsessionid cookie in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

We are using ColdFusion 9.0.1 and are having issues with the JSESSION cookie being shared between a domain and a sub domain.  They are two different websites and we do not wish to share any session information between them.

How do I add a value to the domain field of the jsessionid cookie?  I've seen some examples of people creating a second jsessionid cookie manually but I would rather stick to just one.

Comment: Sessions are tied to application name, so incorporate the host_name into that should in theory prevent them being shared, once setdomaincookies is disabled.

Comment: @PeterBoughton You are correct but the problem is that with IE you can end up with two JSESSION id cookies and then when it gets confused as to which one to use.  Particularly after expiring the cookie with a NOW time value.

Comment: I guess a question is, do you _need_ jsessionid / does the problem occur with regular cfid?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the domain is set on the cookie by default which should limit it to the same domain, perhaps someone has edited your jrun-web.xml file and hard coded a value (look for cookie-domain tag)? See http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/Programmers_Guide/techniques_servlet13.htm for more info.